# How to return an object into a different scope in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I want to return some data from a form as an object when I submit the form but I am having trouble getting the data to be in the object in the correct scope. I am not sure why console logging the newEvent variable within the onsubmit event handler returns an event either.

How can I access the returned form data in the outer scope?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/antfish/crp98hhw/40/

```
var createTaskForm = document.getElementById('create-task'),
    newTask = new Object();

    //Returns empty object (I would like my returned object accessible in this scope)
    console.log(newTask);

function getFormData(id, newTask) {
    var createTaskForm = document.getElementById(id),
        formElements = createTaskForm.elements;

    createTaskForm.onsubmit = function(newTask) {
        var title = formElements['todo-title'].value,
            content = formElements['todo-content'].value;

        newTask.title = title;
        newTask.content = content;

        //Returns Event
        console.log(newTask);

        return newTask;

    }

}

getFormData('create-task');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `newTask` as an input argument to both `getFormData` and `createTaskForm.onsubmit`, you are redeclaring that variable within the scope of those functions.  To access the value from the outer scope, you just need to reference it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated the JS in this fiddle, but my second console log is still returning undefined. I must be missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/antfish/51xb8z76/5/

Answer (score 0):

You call `getFormData` with no second argument despite defining `getFormData` to take 2 arguments.

But the second parameter of `getFormData` is unused anyway it the function's body, so I don't know why it's there.

Also the globally defined `createTaskForm` variable is never used.

At any rate, if you want the `newTask` object that you defined in the global scope to be assigned to by the `onsubmit` callback created by `getFormData`, just remove the `newTask` parameter from both `getFormData` and the inner anonymous function. This way, both will close over the global `newTask` object (i.e. refer to it) and the submit event will cause `newTask` to be modified.

Remark: `getFormData` is very poorly named, since it returns nothing. It should be named `setOnsubmitCallback` or something.

Example:

```
var newTask = {}; // this is simpler than "new Object()"

function setOnsubmitCallback(formId)
{
    var createTaskForm = document.getElementById(id);
    var formElements = createTaskForm.elements;

    createTaskForm.onsubmit = function () {
        // do your stuff with the newTask object
    };
}

setOnsubmitCallback('create-task');
```

Now, every time the submit event is triggered (e.g. by clicking an `<input type="submit">` element or something) your callback will be called, and the `newTask` object will contain the appropriate data.

**edit:** The reason why `console.log(newTask);` returned an event is the following: the DOM (document object model) is made such that when it calls a callback bound to a DOM event ("onsubmit" being one of those), it passes to the callback function a first argument which is an Event object. Hence, when it called your callback, the value of `newTask` was that event object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, there were some relics of old revisions of code that hadn't been removed (hence global var not being called) also the function is supposed to do more than it currently does, the current name isn't well named as you say.

I have edited the code, but with my understanding of what you've said then the second console log in this fiddle should contain the populated object? Not sure what I'm missing here.

http://jsfiddle.net/antfish/51xb8z76/5/

Comment: @Antfish No it should not. As I told you, the `getFormData` __binds an event listener to the `onsubmit` event__ which means that it simply says "when the form gets submitted, this function should be called". If you don't trigger the event, that is to say if you don't submit the form, then logging the `newTask` object is simply going to log whatever value is set on it at the time. You want to log the object only after the form has been submitted. Execute your code, then click on the submit button, then in you browser's console log the `newTask` object and you will see it has been populated.